# twilio bhrowser to browser call issue?

Tags: php, twilio

I am following http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/browser-to-browser-calls for making a call from browser to browse.

According to documentation open two browser with:

http://127.0.0.1/client.php?client=test1 and 127.0.0.1/client.php?client=test2

When I am using sandbox APP ID:

```
The both browser couldn't able to connect but it a call connect to the the sandbox number.
```

When I am using my app ID:
It shows me the following error:

```
Component: TwiML errors
httpResponse: 502
ErrorCode: 11200
url: http://127.0.0.1/demo.php



Request: What Twilio sent your server
         HTTP Method:   GET
         HTTP URL:  http://127.0.0.1/demo.php
         HTTP BODY: Key Value
         AccountSid xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         ApplicationSid dddddddddddddddddddddddddd
         Caller client:jenny
         CallStatus ringing
         Called 
         To 
         PhoneNumber    tommy
         CallSid    cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
         From   client:jenny
         Direction  inbound
         ApiVersion 2010-04-01

Response: What your web application responded with to Twilio
         HTTP Headers:  Key Value
         Date   Thu, 25 Aug 2011 11:36:22 GMT
         Content-Length 137
         Connection close
         Content-Type   text/html
         Server TwilioProxy/0.7

with <html><head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body><h1>Bad Gateway</h1>An upstream server returned an invalid response.</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VoiceURL assigned to your application must be a publicly-accessible URL so that the Twilio servers can reach it. If it's running only 127.0.0.1 that is only accessible from your local machine and we can't reach it.

You may be interested in something like [localtunnel.com](http://www.localtunnel.com) or [ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) which will let you expose your local server to the public.